# Federated Authentication with Space in Site Name

Tags: sxa, federated-authentication

I have several SXA sites with spaces in the site name. When enabling federated login for a site containing a space in the name I get the following error on the redirect.

> "Site from query string was not found: My%20Website"

It's obviously encoding the space. Renaming all sites without a space would involve code changes. Is it possible to have a space in the name? If so, what is the workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SXA doesn't support spaces in Site names. Here is a link to documentation:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-sxa-site-definition-fields.html

> When you choose a name for the website, you must avoid using characters that are invalid for the website cookies. Therefore, do not use control characters, spaces (" "), semicolons, or commas in your website names.

I remember issues with publishing, there are also issues with built in Sitecore tools like Experience Analytics, caused by spaces in SXA cookies storing site name after opening Experience Editor.

There is no "0-code" fix that would help you with FA and SXA site with space in its name, so you can either;

- make your site compliant with SXA guidelines by removing spaces from site names
- or you start writing workarounds for all the Sitecore and SXA functionalities and after you fix one thing, you realize that still some 3 others don't work as expected.

My choice would be obvious: remove any illegal characters from SXA site names.

Comment: Thank you. Agree and will remove space